# How to Create Dynamic Containers or Flat buttons inside listview or large continter based on X and Y values in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an example json data

```
  "MyButtons":[
    {
    "shortName":"Garage",
    "shortDesc":"this is the Garage",
    "PkID":"1",
    "height":50, // this is the button/container size height 
    "width":50, // this is the button size width
    "xAxisPoint":251,
    "yAxisPoint":205
    },
    {
    "shortName":"Dining",
    "shortDesc":"Dining desc",
    "tablePkID":"2",
    "height":50,
    "width":50,
    "xAxisPoint":803,
    "yAxisPoint":33
    },
{
    "shortName":"Bedroom",
    "shortDesc":"Bedroom desc",
    "tablePkID":"2",
    "height":50,
    "width":50,
    "xAxisPoint":803,
    "yAxisPoint":33
    }
    ]
```

I will be knowing x and y position inside the image or big outer container, since I am new to flutter unable to figure it out which widget to use and how to insert flat buttons inside the containers dynamically based on x and y values,

[image]

When I press yellow buttons it should give me alert saying you have pressed garage button.

this is the Dart code for the above screenshot

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text(widget.title)),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 0),
                  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: Container(
                    key: _keyRed,
                    child: Container(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(kImage2d)),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ))),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Hello world',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FlatButton. Use **FlatButton** within a **Positioned Widget.**

- List item

- Positioned will help you position the widgets relative to the parent container.
- Positioned should be used within a **Stack Widget.**
- Ideally the Stack Widget's parent should be a container.

[image]

```
 class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              left: 10,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button 1"),
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 250,
              left: 250,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button 2"),
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 400,
              left: 10,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button 3"),
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
            )
          ]),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.green,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 500,
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: @wilz : Pl, let know if this helps.